# How to write htaccess to visit public folders without index.html in Laravel Application?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, laravel-4

I have following inside my .htaccess.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes...
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

My public folder needs to have other public-accessible folders not related to laravel like this.

```
/var/laravel/public/folder1/index.html
```

My problem is when I access the application `www.myapp.com/folder1/index.html` is fine but without `index.html` like this `www.myapp.com/folder1` doesn't work. Browser is saying "Redirect Loop".

I've also set `DocumentIndex index.html` in apache config but still not working. Thanks for shading a light here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can exclude directories from Laravel's rewrite rules by adding a rewrite rule to .htaccess like so:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Excluded Folders...
    RewriteRule ^(folder1|folder2|folder3|e.t.c.)($|/) - [L]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes...
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```